# States Not Working on Highmaps mappoint click

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to change the color and borderColor of a lat/long point on a Highmap when a user clicks it. Currently when a user clicks that point it turns grey with a thick black border and a "glow" effect around it. I would like it to turn a color of my choosing. I have set the options as follows:

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '',
        pointFormat: '{point.name}'
      },
      states: {
        select: {
          color: '#EFFFEF',
          borderColor: 'red'
        },
        hover: {
          color: '#a4edba'
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This does not appear to be working. If I put the same `states` code under `plotOptions.mappoint` there is, again, no change.

I have repurposed the [Highmaps](https://jsfiddle.net/ynr96h4q/) demo with this set up. On that demo if you click on the Basin shape it turns that light green. However, when you click on "Tournai" or "Brussels" or any other point on the map it does not use the `states` option I have set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Remember to set the **allowPointSelect** option to true on series - https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.mappoint.allowPointSelect
- If you want to change the point status on click the state options should be set on **plotOptons.series.marker.states**, not **plotOptions.series.states**,

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wgqcL1ay/

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      marker: {
        fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
        lineWidth: 2,
        lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
        states: {
            select: {
                fillColor: 'red',
                radius: 12,
            }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.mappoint.marker.states.select

Comment: While this works on the demo it does not in our full code. I think the issue is because I have `point.events.click` code in place (we are capturing all points clicked on for use later in page). Updated demo example here: https://jsfiddle.net/ynr96h4q/1/. Would I then need to handle the point color/border in the click event?

Comment: Actually, what fixed this was to set `allowPointSelect: false` when I have `events.point.select` set up.

Comment: It is possible to set the point as select in the `point.events.click` callback. Do you want to set this option and see the demo or `allowPointSelect` set to false is enough solution to you?

Comment: I think I will continue with the `point.events.click` for now but other issues have cropped up with using point clustering - I have made a new question for that.